# How to open the command line in minecraft forge? Also, how do I execute the -Dcofh.rf.crashOnOldAPI=false command?

Tags: command-line, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to open the command line to prevent my forge from crashing. The crash log recommends that I run "-Dcofh.rf.crashOnOldAPI=false" but I don't know where to run it. I've Googled it several times now, but nothing is helping. Anything helps.

Edit: I'm using the standard launcher that comes when you buy the vanilla game from the website.

Comment: How are you launching Minecraft? With Gradle? With Eclipse or some other IDE? With the stock launcher? With MultiMC? With Twitch?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm launching forge with the standard launcher that comes when you buy the base game off the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click "Installations" at the top of the screen, then click "..." next to the installation in question, followed by "Edit". Expand "More options", then look for "JVM Arguments". Add your argument there. Don't remove any that are already there, and make sure you leave a space between yours and the old ones.